# Hide ng-repeat items that don't have matching grandchildren inside two nested ng-repeats

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

Sorry for the cryptic title, but it's a cryptic problem `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

I have 3 nested ng-repeats to represent Google Analytics' account structure. There are several accounts. Each account can have multiple properties, which has multiple views, so: `account -> property -> view`. This is the front-end code:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <label>Search for an estate by name or ID</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="search" search-box="" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat="ac in accounts track by ac.id">
    <h5>{{ac.name}} — <code>{{ac.id}}</code>
      </h5>
    <div class="well well-sm">
      <div ng-repeat="prop in ac.properties track by prop.id" ng-show="filteredViews.length > 0">
        <h6> – {{prop.name}} — <code>{{prop.id}}</code>
          </h6>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="view in prop.views | viewFilter:search as filteredViews track by view.id">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="selectedEstates" checklist-value="view" /> {{view.name}} — <code>{{view.id}}</code>
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and this picture is what it looks like when rendered with a randomly generated hierarchy. You can see that under the 2 accounts there are several properties, with views under each of them.

[image: Nested accounts, properties and views]

There is a search bar above this. The idea is for the user to be able to search by either view name or view ID. When the user types, **only the accounts and properties that have matching views should remain**. The rest should be hidden.

However with my current implementation I can only hide the properties that don't have matching children, **not** the non-matching accounts. Eg:

[image]

My question is, how do I hide the accounts that don't have matching views (grandchildren)?

**PLUNKER**: https://plnkr.co/edit/hvicwa5slPJlpGOfoitn?p=preview

Comment: PS if anyone has any tips on how to make this question any more concise I'd be happy to oblige.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve this using one more filter on property.  Hope this will help you

Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/EOP3rDT92z2tez4gblsg?p=preview

```
app.filter('propFilter', function() {
return function(prop, searchTerm) {

  var filteredProps = [];

  for (var k = 0; k < prop.length; k++) {
  var estates =  prop[k].views
  for (var i = 0; i < estates.length; i++) {
    var view = estates[i];

    if (~view.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toUpperCase()) || ~view.id.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toUpperCase())) {
      filteredProps.push(prop[k]);
      break;
    }
  }
  }

 return filteredProps;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works excellently. I tried to go down the path of having a simple `ng-show` based on a variable, but it looks like you can't do that without another filter.

Answer (score -1):

Generally, you can use the `ng-if` directive to hide DOM elements. `ng-if` inserted into a DOM declaration will make the DOM display if the value inside `ng-if` is true and hide it otherwise.

You should probably check using `ng-if` declaration if there are any "grandchildren."

Comment: I'm aware of `ng-if`, the problem is a bit more complex. Specifically to check how many members are in a descendant's filtered array.